# Oracle SQL: loop count overlaps between values in the the same column

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

I have a table which look like the one below:

```
Form_ID   Values
1            a
1            b
1            c
1            d
2            a
2            d
2            e
3            d
3            e
3            f
```

I have more than 200 forms and 10,000+ values from these forms. So I want to do a loop using SQL to count overlapped distinct value between each form. For example, the distinct count between form1 and form2 is 2. The result table should look like:

```
Form1    Form2   Overlap_Count
1         2           2
2         3           2
```

Thanks!
Sophia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Select t1.form_Id form1, t2.Form_Id form2, 
       count(*) overLAPS
From table t1
   join table t2
      on t2.Form_ID > t1.form_Id
         and t2.[Values] = t1.[Values]
group by t1.form_Id, t2.Form_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a self-join and aggregation:

```
select t1.id, t2.id, count(*) as NumOverlaps
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id < t2.id and t1.value = t2.value
group by t1.id, t2.id;
```

Comment: Thanks! In Oracle 11g, it is overLAPS.